# Install package from private registry using Yarn in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

I try to install packages from a private registry using yarn in a docker image, so we reuse this image in other pipelines. When I use npm everything works fine, but as soon I use yarn i get 404's.

Using NPM it is working fine:

```
RUN npm config set @my-scope:registry https://registry.npmjs.org && \
    npm config set //registry.npmjs.org:_authToken ${AUTH_TOKEN_PRIVATE_REGISTRY}

RUN npm i @my-scope/my-package # success!
```

And when using Yarn:

```
RUN yarn config set @my-scope:registry https://registry.npmjs.org && \
    yarn config set //registry.npmjs.org:_authToken ${AUTH_TOKEN_PRIVATE_REGISTRY}

RUN yarn add @my-scope/my-package # 404!
```

I'm really wondering what I'm doing wrong when using Yarn. I see quite some options to login via the CLI, which will work but I need to have the process automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials I solved it by adding 2 files: the `.yarnrc` and `.npmrc`.

The `.yarnrc` contains the following:

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
```

The `.npmrc` contains:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

You can now remove the `yarn config set` lines from Docker, and run `yarn add @my-scope/foo-bar` to install your package.